# What would the determinant of the following matrix be?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

" If $$\det\begin{pmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&1&e\\ c&1&f\end{pmatrix}=4$$

and $$\det
\begin{pmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&2&e\\ c&3&f\end{pmatrix}=3$$

What is $$\det \begin{pmatrix}a&-1&d\\ b&-3&e\\ c&-5&f\end{pmatrix}?$$"

This does not seem to fit into any of the regular changes in the values of matrices. A row does not seem to be multiplied. It does not seem like a row is being added to another. So how would I find the required determinant?

Comment: If you subtract $2$ times the second column from the second column of the first matrix, you obtain the third matrix.

Comment: Notice that the determinant is linear in each column

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$\det \begin{pmatrix}a&-1&d\\ b&-3&e\\ c&-5&f\end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix}a&1-2\times1&d\\ b&1-2\times 2&e\\ c&1-2\times 3&f\end{pmatrix}=\det \begin{pmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&1&e\\ c&1&f\end{pmatrix}-2\det \begin{pmatrix}a&1&d\\ b&2&e\\ c&3&f\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Best and shortest answer here

Answer (score 5):

Let $$p = -\begin{vmatrix}b & e \\ c & f\end{vmatrix}, q= \begin{vmatrix}a & d \\ c & f\end{vmatrix}, r=-\begin{vmatrix}a & d \\ b & e\end{vmatrix}$$

The question can be rephrase as follows:

If $$p+q+r=4$$

and $$p+2q+3r=3$$

Find:

$$-p-3q-5r$$